# How to trigger servlet execution on application start?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

[working with JEE, MVC, servlets, JSP]
In `web.xml` i have specified `home.jsp` page as application entry point:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In my application I have next servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/show")
public class ShowPostsController extends HttpServlet {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @EJB
   private PostDAOLocal postDao;

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
   throws ServletException, IOException 
   {

         List<Post> posts = null;

         String sort = request.getParameter("sort"); 
         // current page number
         int page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")); 
         // the number of entries to show on a "page" 
         int postsPerPage = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("postsPerPage")); 

         if(sort.equals("byVisitors"))
          posts = postDao.getMostVisitedPosts();
         else if(sort.equals("byComments"))
          posts = postDao.getMostCommentedPosts();
         else
              posts = postDao.getNewestPosts(page, postsPerPage);  

        request.setAttribute("posts", posts);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Now, how can I make make this servlet to be invoked before `home.jsp` page is loaded, on application start? (because I would like to display some data on `home.jsp` that are being extracted from database, and set as request attributes inside servlet's `doGet` method)

Comment: You can't do it at app startup because there's no request at app startup.

Comment: @Sotirios Yes, thats why I don't know how to send those `posts` data to `home.jsp` page.

Comment: You use your servlet as is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but, how to send those `posts` list to `home.jsp`? Or is there some different approach to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, how can I make make this servlet to be invoked before home.jsp page is loaded, on application start?

If by "on application start" you mean "when the application is accessed for the first time by a user using the default path" and all you want is the servlet to be called by default instead of the jsp, then try replacing `/home.jsp` by `/show` in your `welcome-file-list`, e.g.:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/show</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

If it doesn't work, try without the leading slash before `show`.

**Edit**: Regarding the other question in the comments. To use default values, you can check if `getParameter()` returns null and if it does, assign a default value to the local variable, e.g.:

```
String sort = request.getParameter("sort"); 
if (sort == null) {
    sort = "someDefaultValue";
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What doesn't work? Is there are error message?

Comment: my appologies. it does load servlet. I was getting exception because of the code in `doGet` method, where request parameters are being read. Now, how can I check that if it is application start, to put some initial values to these attributes (`sort, page, postsPerPage`)? I mean when those parameters are not in request but servlet is invoked.

Comment: thanks for help. I was opinion that servlet can't be set as app entry point. Obviously wrong (still learning)

Answer (score 1):

Do load a servlet on application start you need to edit the web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>******</servlet-name>
<display-name>******</display-name>
<servlet-class>******</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: ok, i have added `loadOnStartup=1` as parameter in @WebServlet(I am using annotation). But now, if you take a look at servlet content I am reading some data from database(`posts`), adding it to request as `request.setAttribute("posts", posts);` and forwarding to `home.jsp`. How to make this same actions being executed on app startup? Because on `home.jsp` I am displaying those `posts` data.

Comment: Why dont you set whatever you need in your session on your servlet. Further, from home.jsp you can access the required data from your session

Comment: well, on app startup there is not `request` so how can i use session then?

Comment: True. What is it that you need to do exactly ? I am sure there will be another way of doing it.

Comment: if you look at the servlet `doGet` method content, I would like on app start to call method `getNewestPosts` on `DAO` object, and pass that result somehow to `home.jsp` page where I am reading those data.

Comment: When is home.jsp called ?

Comment: I have set servlet to be application entry point(instead of `home.jsp`) - `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml`. So, i set certain attributes to request inside servlet and forwards to `home.jsp`. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: This may not be the correct technique. The servlet init method will be  invoked only one when the app loads in tomcat. Suppose you manage to set whatever you need in this, what will happen if another user comes to home.jsp. I think you should change your strategy

Comment: Servlet `init()` method is not used. Now, when I have specified `<welcome-file>show</welcome-file>` in `web.xml`, I have removed `loadOnStartup` for servlet, no need for that. Now, when application starts, servlets `doGet` method is invoked. Not sure, but probably there isn't request when client only types applications URL.But when servlet path is set as `<welcome-file>` then servlets `doGet` method is invoked. Wanted to see what is the value of `Referer` header I have put next line inside `doGet`: `System.out.println("Referer: " + request.getHeader("Referer"));` and it prints `null`.